# How to detect if a specific scheduled task is running?

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

I've 2 specific scheduled tasks on my windows 2008 Server

- The first runs once a day
- The second runs every five minutes.

In the second task, that is basically a php script, I'd like to check if the first task is running and, if yes, to exit / avoid to run.

So the question is: is there a way to check from command line if a specific task is running?

Comment: [tasklist](http://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html) - TaskList displays all running applications and services with their Process ID (PID) This can be run on either a local or a remote computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using plain MSDOS, you can do:

```
schtasks /query /TN my-task-name /FO LIST
```

And extract the output. As an example I do:

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=2,*" %%f in (`schtasks /query /TN my-task-name /FO LIST ^| findstr Status`) do set status=%%f %%g
if "%status%" EQU "Running" goto :eof
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Get-ScheduledTask](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/get-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps) and [Get-ScheduledTaskInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/get-scheduledtaskinfo?view=win10-ps) command in PowerShell.

Comment: Hi Andre and welcome. Consider improving your answer with actual code or example that illustrates the solution. For example `(Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName MyTask).State -eq "Running"` returns true if `MyTask` is running. Did you have other solution, possibly involving the mentioned `Get-ScheduledTaskInfo`?

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík: thanks a lot for your comment! I tried using Where State -eq "Running" but it returns true even if a process is not running, because the get itself run without problem. I'll try your syntax ASAP.